# Draftwatermark Package unwanted font change

Tags: draftwatermark

I am using the `draftwatermark` package and with a document that contains `verbatim` sections. This is an usual/unwanted outcome where the current page (or next page) formatting is effecting the font of the `DRAFT` mark made on the pages.

How can I control the font?

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\begin{verbatim}
    {
    "aaaaaaaa": {
        "aaaa": "aaaaaa",
        "aaaa": "aaaaaaa",
        "aa": 000,
        "aaaaaa_aa": 0,
        "aaaaaaaa_aaaaaa": [
            {
                "aaaa": "aaaaaa",
                "aaaaaaa_aa": "aaaaaaa_aaaaaaa"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "aaaaaaaa": {
        "aaaa": "aaaaaaaa",
        "aaaa": "aaaaa",
        "aa": 00000000,
        "aaaaaa_aa": 000,
        "aaaaaaaa_aaaaaa": [
            {
                "aaaa": "aaaaaaaa",
                "aaaaaaa_aa": "aaaaa_aa_aaaa"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "aaaaaaaa": {
        "aaaa": "aaaaaaa",
        "aaaa": "aaaa",
        "aa": 00000000,
        "aaaaaa_aa": 00000000,
        "aaaaaaaa_aaaaaa": [
            {
                "aaaa": "aaaaaaa",
                "aaaaaaa_aa": "aaaa_aa_aaaa"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "aaaaaaaa": {
        "aaaa": "aaaaaa",
        "aaaa": "aaaaaaa",
        "aa": 000,
        "aaaaaa_aa": 0,
        "aaaaaaaa_aaaaaa": [
            {
                "aaaa": "aaaaaa",
                "aaaaaaa_aa": "aaaaaaa_aaaaaaa"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "aaaaaaaa": {
        "aaaa": "aaaaaa",
        "aaaa": "aaaa",
        "aa": 00000000,
        "aaaaaa_aa": 000,
        "aaaaaaaa_aaaaaa": [
            {
                "aaaa": "aaaaaa",
                "aaaaaaa_aa": "aaaa_aa_aaaa"
            }
        ]
    }
}
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options here. By far the easiest is to "reset" the text to include `\normalfont`:

```
\SetWatermarkText{{\normalfont DRAFT}}
```

Alternatively, you can remove what [`draftwatermark`](//ctan.org/pkg/draftwatermark) inserts in the shipout routine's background layer (`shipout/background`) and reinsert something that includes `\normalfont`:

```
\makeatletter
\RemoveFromHook{shipout/background}[draftwatermark]% Remove default watermark
\AddToHook{shipout/background}[draftwatermark]{%
  {\normalfont\draftwatermark@print{\draftwatermark@markcmd}}%
}
\makeatother
```

The former approach is shown here with a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetWatermarkText{{\normalfont DRAFT}}% Avoid font changes across page boundaries that has font changes

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\ttfamily% Switch to a different font family
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```